# ArrayList empty after passing via Bundle to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist

The Method for putting ArrayLists into `Bundle` and setting an argument for the fragment which will receive it

```
public void finishButtonPressed(){
    ivFinish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MusicFragment fragment = new MusicFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelableArrayList("prgmUri", prgmUri);
            bundle.putStringArrayList("prgmName", prgmName);
            bundle.putStringArrayList("prgmNumber", prgmNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorkoutPreStart.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

The Fragment that has to receive the ArrayLists

```
public class MusicFragment extends Fragment{
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
ImageView ivBack;
ImageView ivPlay;
ImageView ivNext;
TextView tvTitle;
ArrayList<String> prgmName;
ArrayList<String> prgmNumber;
ArrayList<Uri> prgmUri;



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_music, container, false);
    ivBack = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivBack);
    ivPlay = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivPlay);
    ivNext = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivNext);
    tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);


    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    prgmName = new ArrayList<>();
    prgmNumber = new ArrayList<>();
    prgmUri = new ArrayList<>();


    int namesize = prgmName.size();
    Log.v("namesize: ", prgmName.size()+ "");

    for(int i = 0; i<namesize; i++) {
        Log.v("Name: ", prgmName.get(i));
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if(bundle != null) {
        prgmName = bundle.getStringArrayList("prgmName");
        prgmUri = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("prgmUri");
        prgmNumber = bundle.getStringArrayList("prgmNumber");
    }
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), prgmName.get(1) +"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}}
```

I think the reason for having an empty ArrayList is the part in onCreateView:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
prgmName = new ArrayList<>();
prgmNumber = new ArrayList<>();
prgmUri = new ArrayList<>();
```

But if I don't do this I am getting a `NullpointerException`. Even if this question is easy, please help me out, because I already spent more than 10 hours on trying to solve this... :|

Comment: Well the problem is that you are opening a different class setargument() is used when you have to pass data between fragments and not between fragment and activity

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't add the created `MusicFragment` to your activity.
You can do that in [2 ways](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding):

- Dynamically via `FragmentTransaction`, or
- Statically via the activity's layout file

I assume your `MusicFragment` is added in the the `WorkoutPreStart` in the activity's layout. In this case you could add the bundle to the activity's intent and then [pass](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) it to the fragment from the activity.

Comment: My 'MusicFragment' is added to 'WorkoutStart' "Statically via the activity's layout file". Thats the activity where I need the fragment. The 'WorkoutPreStart' class is just a Activity for starting 'WorkoutStart' and 'MusicActivity'

Comment: What is the difference between passing the List directly via Intent, and passing the Bundle which includes the List, via Intent?